# Facebook share button CSS not applying

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook API to make sure my website can be shared through a button.

At that point, the sharing functionality works perfectly fine, but for some reason, it only shows the text inside the button ("share") and not the blue, pretty button that I would like to display.

Here is what it looks like ("Partager" means "Share" in French):

[image: Like that]

[Facebook share debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing) sends me back a "206" response, indicating that everything seems fine.

**The funny part: sometimes the button displays properly, but then I refresh my page and it doesn't work anymore!**

Here is what I did:

**HTML, in the `<head>` tag:**

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.mywebsite.com" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="My description" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.mywebsite.com/img/shareFB.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:app_id"        content="[MY_APP_ID_WHICH_IS_A_NUMBER]"/>
```

**HTML, right after the `<body>`declaration:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    FB.init({
      appId            : '155741968487477',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=[MY_APP_ID_WHICH_IS_A_NUMBER]';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**HTML, where I want the button to display:**

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.mywebsite.com" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">share</a></div>
```

Comment: Maybe try to make it a button, not a div?

Comment: From Facebook's tutorial : <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>.

The formatting is supposed to be made by the CSS classes, that is my problem.

Comment: Woahaha wait a minute, why do you have the <a> inside it? Just put the text in between the div!

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work. Actually I don't want a "count" button so the code I gave you in the previous comment doesn't concern me. This does: <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Partager</a></div>

Comment: _"The formatting is supposed to be made by the CSS classes, that is my problem."_ - no, it is not. First of all, you are not supposed to change the look&feel of any of the social plugins besides the options described for that purpose in the documentation. Secondly, you _can't_ format them using CSS, because they render inside an iframe from a different origin, which you have _no_ access to for such a purpose at all. If you want to use your own button, then _make_ your own, and call the Share or Feed _dialog_ with its `href` or onclick via `FB.ui`

Comment: You misunderstood what I said because I wasn't clear. What I meant is *"The formatting is supposed to be made automatically from the css class fb-share-button and the iframe, and my problem is that this is not being applied automatically"*. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using virtual dom? I had the same issue and when I added the script tags using react-helmet in the exact page as the share buttons, and then a network request to the scripts appeared.

```
<Helmet>
        <meta property="og:url"           content={WEBSITE_URL} />
        <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title"         content={META_TITLE} />
        <meta property="og:description"   content={META_DESCRIPTION} />
        <meta property="og:image"         content={`${WEBSITE_URL}/casino.jpg`} />
        <meta name="twitter:url"          content={WEBSITE_URL}/>
        <meta name="twitter:title"        content={META_TITLE}/>
        <meta name="twitter:description"  content={META_DESCRIPTION}/>
        <meta name="twitter:image"        content={`${WEBSITE_URL}/casino.jpg`} />
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
    <script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</Helmet>
        <a class="twitter-share-button"
            url={WEBSITE_URL}
            href={getURLWithQueryParams({text: "I just won on Clover Casino!"}, "https://twitter.com/")}>
            Tweet
          </a>

          <div class="fb-share-button" 
          data-size="large"

            data-href={TEMP_WEBSITE_URL_WITH_DOMAIN}
            data-layout="button" data-size="small">
            <a
              href={getURLWithQueryParams({u: WEBSITE_URL}, "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php")}
              class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
              share
            </a>
          </div>
```